# If there are two highest value, how to print both

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(First_Name, ' ' , Last_Name) AS [Player Name], GWG 
FROM
    nhl 
ORDER BY
    GWG DESC;
```

[image]

Here there are two players that have the highest values of 12; I need to print both names without using TOP or limit. I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `TOP` to select the top records? It is possible to do it without, just wondering why you are ruling out the exact syntax created for your scenario?

Comment: What's the problem with using `top` and why do you think `limit` is even an option with SQL Server?

Comment: Suppose the question is to find the player who has the max GWS. Now, there is two players that I came to know by running the query once.  So, i want to know is it possible to get the player name without using TOP or limit.

Comment: It seems you want [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in a CTE with a filter on value 1.

Comment: I tried to explain the query, but it wasn't effective. Imagine if there are 100 player that has same GWS score. so, will I be counting all those and then printing top 100 or there is any other method to get the result of those player has the maximin score.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can't use `TOP`, @Jyoti . Why, specifically, are you not allowed to use the operator?

Comment: This is a good example of asking about an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and something to learn about - by not knowing how to do X you have assumed the only alternative is Y and have asked a question about how to do Y, instead of explaining that you need to do X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* you're not aware of `with ties`.

Using

```
Select top(1) with ties
  CONCAT(First_Name, ' ' , Last_Name) as [Player Name], 
  GWG 
from nhl 
order by GWG desc;
```

Will give you only the row(s) with the maximum value of `GWG`

Answer (score 0):

Why the focus on NOT using TOP? Typically questions that seek to avoid some feature often are "solution" to different issues that are better addressed in a different manner. But here is one method.

```
with cte as (select max(GWG) as mGWG from dbo.nhl)
select ... 
  from dbo.nhl as nhl 
 inner join cte on nhl.GWG = cte.mGWG
order by ...
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(First_Name, ' ' , Last_Name) AS [Player Name], GWG 
FROM
    nhl 
JOIN (select max(GWG) as GWG from nhl) maxGWG on nhl.GWG = maxGWG.GWG
;
```

or

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(First_Name, ' ' , Last_Name) AS [Player Name], GWG 
FROM
    nhl 
where GWG in (select max(GWG) from nhl)
;
```